# Android TextWatcher for number

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Задача такая. Нужно реализовать TextWatcher с таким выводам:

```
2,
200,
2 000,
20 000,
200 000,
2 000 000,
20 000 000,
200 000 000
```

Я пытался долго реализовать это не получалось. Даже попадал в бесконечной цикл. Так и не понял почему. Помогите пожалуйста
Вот код:

```
public class PriceTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
private static final char space = ' ';

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //Remove spacing char
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) {
            final char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (space == c) s.delete(i , i+1);
        }
    }

    //Log.e(Controller.TAG , "unspaces: " + s.toString());
    if (s.length() == 4) s.insert(1 , String.valueOf(space));
    else if (s.length() == 5) s.insert(2 , String.valueOf(space));
    else if (s.length() == 6) s.insert(2 , String.valueOf(space));
    //Log.e(Controller.TAG , "new: " + s.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Сложновато это реализовать самописным кодом, особенно если учитывать локализацию (не везде принято разделять тысячи пробелом). Лучше задействовать готовый форматер, например как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12546391

Comment: @woesss здравствуйте. Локализация не играет роли. Требуется такой вывод

Comment: @woesss Спасибо. Ваша ссылка мне очень помогла